# Remove everything that doesn't match regex patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a regex pattern that identifies dates in a whole column of dates, but some of the dates are included in a string, while some are just plain dates by themselves.  My regex pattern finds every date perfectly, but now I wanted to be able to say "remove everything that doesn't fit the date pattern" which will get rid of the text that's either in front of or behind some dates.

Example of the stuff I want gone:

`Mexico [12/20/1985]` If I could remove what doesn't match the pattern, then the brackets and Mexico would go away

Say my regex pattern is (I have two more that match more specific date formats but not including them because that's beside the point:

`pattern = (r"(19|20)\d\d")`

I'm using `has_date = data.str.contains(pattern)` and it works perfectly to find what I'm looking for. But, now that I've identified the observations that have the dates that I want, I need to strip/remove/replace with nothing everything that isn't that pattern.

I made a file of what didn't match the regex patterns and what did, and checked to make sure my regex patterns got everything, so I'm good on that front.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to replace what isn't my pattern? Welcome any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you want to *extract* texts your pattern matches. Try `df['Dates'] = df['Data'].str.extract(r'\b((?:19|20)\d{2})\b', expand=False).fillna('')` (if `Data` is the column with original texts and `Dates` is the target column).

Comment: Have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your exact problem, namely replacing everything not matching the pattern, you may use

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.replace(r"(?s)((?:19|20)\d\d)?.", r"\1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DTbk8/1).

Here, `(?s)` will make `.` match any char, `((?:19|20)\d\d)?` is an optional capturing group #1 that matches either `19` or `20` and then any 2 digits 1 or 0 times, and then matches any char with `.` pattern. If Group 1 matched, it will be put back into the result due to the `\1` backreference.

However, it seems you want to just extract the year from the data, and in case there is none, just get an empty string, so use

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.extract(r'\b((?:19|20)\d{2})\b', expand=False).fillna('')
```

The `\b((?:19|20)\d{2})\b` will match `19` or `20` and then any two digits as a whole word (due to `\b` word boundaries).

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry for the late response, but I hadn't been able to get into my account. That solution was very helpful